# Easy hash function collision

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

I'm designing a cryptography-breaking assignment for a college-level introductory security course, and I'm looking for a hash function which is reasonably easy (but not too easy) to generate collisions for. The assignment is that the students are given a hash table implementation which uses such a function, and their task is to design a series of inputs which will tank the hash table's performance. I was originally thinking of modelling it off of PHP's associative array attack from a few years ago, but it's actually *too* simple (for integer keys, the index used is literally just the integer modded by the table size). Any ideas for something that might be a tad harder than this, but not so hard that a bunch of sophomores with a week's worth of crypto lectures couldn't solve it in a reasonable amount of time?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** To clarify, I'm looking for hash functions which are not cryptographically secure, and can be easily inverted (or at the very least caused to collide) without brute-force search of the input space. As a general rule, hash functions which you could even mistake for cryptographically secure are probably too hard to break for this assignment.

Comment: CRC32? Or one with your own polynomial if you want to avoid them just googling a solution.

Comment: I’ld like to chime in with @otus… if that’s too hard, you could opt-in to a simpler CRC16 or maybe even CRC8. The later being near to a “pen-and-paper effort” assignment, yet nice enough to activate their brain. And if you need it a tad more difficult than CRC32, you could go for CRC64. Wikipedia has [a table which might help (scroll down)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#), and also lists [some Polynomial representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_representations_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks) which you could adapt to your own preferences as otus indicated.

Answer (score 2):

A mathematically elegant and rather simple way of hashing are the parity bits of a Hamming code, as small changes in the data will yield different parity bits. You can weakly hash 4-bit strings to 3-bit strings with the standard (7,4) Hamming code, but the general Hamming code construction has high enough rate that you can hash longer strings (say, 26 bits to 5 bits) with a very simple algorithm and give them a hint by showing how to break the (7,4) hash.

Actually, it does sound like a fun homework assignment to find a string of length $2^{20} - 21$ that hashes to a particular $20$ bit string using a $(2^{20}-1, 2^{20}-21)$ Hamming code

Of course there are better "real hashes", but you didn't want that, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can tune the difficulty of finding collisions very simply by reducing the number of output bits from any hash function.

For example, if you take SHA-256 and reduce it to SHA-13 (by only returning the 13 least significant bits of the output), it becomes a far weaker hash function.  Now the probability of finding a collision is a mere 1 in 2^13 for each attempt.  If that's too weak, try SHA-42 or whatever you like.

Comment: I'd like this to be a non-brute force break. That is, the students should be able to identify some simple theoretical weakness. I was thinking, for example, of a prime modulus hash (where `H(x, y) = p1x + p2y mod m` for some `p1`, `p2` and some prime `m`), but the modular arithmetic involved in breaking it is pretty tricky if you haven't seen the algebra before.

Comment: SHA-13 collision attack would require only about $2^7$ attempts, though I suppose you might as well use a 2nd preimage attack in that case.

Comment: Finding a specific collision, I should have said.